# Windows Store deployment file from folder instead of MSI

Tags: c++, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-installer

I want to ask you a couple of questions i looked in internet and didn't found an answer though...

I have an application for windows 10 PCx64 (artifacts of a built project C++/x64)

1. Is it possible to create odrinary Windows Store deployment file from folder?
2. How to do that? As i see MS is pushing new 'universal applciations' concept. But i don't want to rewrite apps entirely to .net/c#/Universal Apps. I just want to change build process so it will produce windows store deployment file, not MSI

Thanks!

Comment: Your question 1 sounds a lot like [sideloading a Windows Store application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx), but even that assumes one of the newfangled app packages (i.e., contradicts with question 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will soon be able to create a Windows Store package for a Win32 app and deploy it through the Windows Store. You'll even get access to UWP APIs and services :)

Subscribe to the "Windows Developer Preview Programs" to get some fresh news about "Project Centennial".

https://devpreviewsignup.windows.com/